# Undefined variable - laravel emailing

Tags: php, laravel, email

I'm trying to send an email using laravel. This worked for serveral functions but with this one I'm getting a weird error.

here's the code I'm using

```
    $offerte = DB::table('offertes')
        ->select('*')
        ->where('id', '=', $offerte_id)
        ->get();

    Mail::send('emails.offerte_reactie', ['offerte' => $offerte, 'user' => $user, 'message_text' => $message_text], function ($message) use ($user)
    {
        $message->from($user->email, 'Foodtruckbestellen.be');
        $message->to($offerte->email);
        $message->subject('Reactie offerte Foodtruckbestellen.be');
    });
```

However when I want to send the mail I get the error

> Undefined variable: offerte

The line **$message->to($offerte->email);** is indeed underlined in red in PHPSTORM and I don't use the variable in the email. so I know for sure that's where my error is I just can't find a fix for it.

Comment: It looks like you're not returning anything from the database. Did you check that sql statement by itself and make sure that id exists?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass the `$offerte` variable to closure as it's not defined within the closure scope.

Just use the `$offerte`variable as you do with the `$user`.

```
Mail::send('emails.offerte_reactie', ['offerte' => $offerte, 'user' => $user, 'message_text' => $message_text], function ($message) use ($user, $offerte)
{
    $message->from($user->email, 'Foodtruckbestellen.be');
    $message->to($offerte->email);
    $message->subject('Reactie offerte Foodtruckbestellen.be');
});
```

Furthermore, if I were you, I'd use [`compact`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) for the array that you pass to the send function's second argument to write more clean code.

```
Mail::send('emails.offerte_reactie', compact('offerte', 'user', 'message_text'), function ($message) use ($user, $offerte)
{
    $message->from($user->email, 'Foodtruckbestellen.be');
    $message->to($offerte->email);
    $message->subject('Reactie offerte Foodtruckbestellen.be');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You shoud add variable $offerte to use function like that :

```
    Mail::send('emails.offerte_reactie', ['offerte' => $offerte, 'user' => $user, 'message_text' => $message_text], function ($message) use ($user,$offerte)
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to write **$offerte** variable hence.

```
Mail::send('emails.offerte_reactie', ['offerte' => $offerte, 'user' => $user, 'message_text' => $message_text], function ($message) use ($user, $offerte)
```