# Laravel 'Undefined variable:' in User Controller

Tags: php, laravel

I want to sent thanks mail when users regist our service.
But, This code is error `Undefined variable: fhbvuileb` in `$message->to($fhbvuileb)`.
Help ME!!!

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{

  /** ~~~ **/

  protected function create(array $data)
  {

    $fhbvuileb = $data['email'];
    Mail::send('emails.user_register', ["message" => "Hello!"], function($message) {
      $message->to($fhbvuileb)
              ->subject("Thank you!!!");
    });
    return User::create([
      'name' => $data['name'],
      'email' => $data['email'],
      'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);

  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undefined variable - laravel emailing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37967384/undefined-variable-laravel-emailing)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the variable inside the Mail callback function.
What you have written is called Closure, and hence the variable is not available inside the closure function scope.

There is a keyword in PHP called `use` which makes this `$fhbvuileb` inside the function.

```php
$fhbvuileb = $data['email'];
    Mail::send('emails.user_register', ["message" => "Hello!"], function($message) use($fhbvuileb) {
      $message->to($fhbvuileb)
              ->subject("Thank you!!!");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use language construct  `use()` to pass any argument from the parent scope

```
   Try this:
    Mail::send('emails.user_register', ["message" => "Hello!"], function($message) use($fhbvuileb) {
              $message->to($fhbvuileb)
                      ->subject("Thank you!!!");
            });
```

Comment: Pasting code isn't an answer. Please explain what your code fixed.